# using if-elif-else statments for adding two integers

Tags: python, if-statement

I have just starting learning python and as I creating this program, which asks user to input two numbers, which then adds them to together using a simple  `if-elif-else`  statement, however the else part of the code just seems to not work if, an user types out the six, for example,  in words instead of the number.

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
Total = num_1 + num_2

print("The total is: ",Total)

if num_1 > num_2:
    print("num_1 is greater then num_2")
elif num_2 > num_1:
    print("num_2 is greater then num_1")
elif num_1 == num_2:
    print("Equal")
else:
   if num_1 == str:
       if num_2 == str:
           print("invalid")
```

Comment: when do you think `num1` is neither greater, smaller nor equal to `num2`?

Comment: If the user inputs `six`, your code won't progress past the `int()` part of that `int(input(...))`. Nevertheless, there is no possible combination of `num1` and `num2` that would fulfill the criteria for your code to enter the `else`

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question. Please read [ask]. Maybe you want to ask, "Why doesn't `int()` convert the string `"six"` to the integer `6`?", but I don't know why you'd expect that it would. `int()` can convert strings that represent integer literals like `"6"`, but not number words like `"six"`. For reference see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
try:
    num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
except ValueError:
   print("invalid")
   exit()
Total = num_1 + num_2
print("The total is: ", Total)

if num_1 > num_2:
    print("num_1 is greater then num_2")
elif num_2 > num_1:
    print("num_2 is greater then num_1")
else:
    print("Equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first two lines you’re calling int() on a string in the situation you’re describing. This won’t work, and your code will stop running here. What you want is probably something call a try-catch statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).